# How to use node-sphericalmercator?

Tags: google-maps, mercator

How to use node-sphericalmercator? There is no any valuable examples on their github page https://github.com/mapbox/node-sphericalmercator

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? For example, in order to compute the bounding box of a given tile, you can call `new SphericalMercator({size: 256}).bbox(x, y, z)`.

---